# MS SSRS 2017 Rolling timeframe option

Tags: sql-server, email, reporting-services, rolling-computation, ssrs-2017

new user here.
Summary: I have a set of already created custom reports in SSRS and it can be viewed and printed through a GUI. Now, I want to set up an email subscription for one of the reports on SSRS. It will be a daily report summarizing data of the day before.
After looking at some tutorials,  I was able to set up the email subscription with the parameters I want to show. However, the daily reports sent out is only showing the start and end time of whatever I entered in the subscription.

For Example if the initial DTS I entered are 
Start: Feb 5th 00:00
End: Feb 5th 23:59
it will still send this report everyday with the same data from Feb 5th.

I want it to be able to update itself to use the date and time of the day before, a rolling timeframe instead of a fixed timeframe. Can I do this in a regular email subscription, or do i need to use a data driven subscription?

If you need any more clarification, please let me know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with your regular email subscription. You need to use report builder or SSRS to define the default start and end date time values for your parameter.

Try this for your start date default value:

```
=DateAdd("d",-1,Today())
```

Try this for your end date default value:

```
=DateAdd("s", -1, Today())
```

After you deploy this report and set up the subscription again, make sure the parameters are using default value. They will default to the day before report date.